# String#to_i does not work when using string object parsed from a csv file

Tags: ruby, string, csv, integer

I'm using `CSV` class to read a csv file with Ruby.

Here is my code

```
CSV.foreach('../../../db/data/xxxx.csv') do |row|
  # ...
  row[0].to_i
  # ...
end
```

File `'../../../db/data/xxxx.csv'` surely exists. `row[0]` returns `"1"`.
So I expect `row[0].to_i` to return `1`, but `row[0].to_i` returns `0`. I thought it is encoding matter of `row[0].encoding`, but it returns `#<Encoding:UTF-8>`.

```
row[0]
#=> "1"
row[0].class
#=> String
row[0].encoding
#=> Encoding:UTF-8
row[0] == "1"
#=> false
```

Does anyone help me?

Comment: What does `row[0].codepoints` return?

Comment: thanks for quick response.

it returns

`
 row[0].codepoints
=> [65279, 49]
`

Comment: Seems like your CSV file contains a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)